# Exclude Java Source using Spring Boot Maven Plugin at Build time

Tags: spring-boot, toggle, maven-compiler-plugin, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I have a requirement to exclude certain Java source files from being compiled as part of the final build when running the Maven build.

I am using Spring Boot Maven plugin in my Spring Boot based project.

I am looking for a way to exclude Java source files from being compiled and corresponding Junit test classes also need to be excluded from the final build at build time.

Is there a way to achieve the same using the Spring Boot Maven Plugin?

Comment: Someone correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't that what the `src/test/java` directory tree is for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I achieved this by configuring maven-compiler-plugin:

pom.xml

```
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <excludes>
            <exclude>com/example/compileexclude/ExcludedJavaClass.java</exclude>
          </excludes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
```

For reference you can see all available config options [here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/).